# Use JavaScript confirm dialog to make a PHP call in the background

Tags: php, javascript, function

OK, not really sure if this is possible but thought I'd ask anyway :)

I have a HTML page which contains some information and a link.
The link calls a JavaScript confirm dialog box.
If the user selects OK then I want to call a function in a PHP file, but in the background, i.e I don't want to change page, reload or anything.

Is this possible?

Thanks

T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AJAX.  The following uses jQuery:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file.php',
        data: 'url=encoded&query=string', // Can also be an object
        success: function(output) {
            // This function is called after the PHP file completes.
            // The variable passed in is a string containing all output of
            // your PHP script (i.e. echo / print )
        }
    });
}
```

For more information, check out jQuery's documentation for [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  If you cannot use jQuery, there are many [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=native%20ajax&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=gl6&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=native%20ajax%20tutorial&oq=native%20ajax%20tutorial&aq=f&aqi=q-w1&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.16874.17643.0.17761.9.7.0.0.0.0.151.621.3j3.6.0.eish.1.0.0.u2DIxOXf6cE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1dc8ed790bd95263&biw=1680&bih=919) on using native JavaScript to make AJAX Requests.

If you are returning a large amount of data back to your success function from PHP, it would be worthwhile for you to return the data from PHP as a [JSON encoded array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), which can be safely [parsed](http://www.json.org/js.html) client-side into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.LinkClass').click(function(){

  if( confirm('Is it OK?') ) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'data=value', // Can also be an object
        success: function(data) {
            // Do Nothing
        },
        error: function(){
           alert('Error');
        }
    });

  }

});
```